# Why does dragged DragSource have odd style and no-entry icon?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

My items are draggable, but in Chrome, for example, they have an odd opacity gradient filter and the no-entry pointer attached.

Why doesn't the item look like the item before it's dragged?

Incidentally, it only does this on Windows Chrome, not on Mac Chrome. On Mac Chrome there's only a slight opacity effect.

Microsoft Edge doesn't have the gradient effect, but it does show a no-entry icon on the dragged item.

I'd attach some screen shots but I can't work out how to do them whilst dragging an item.

Comment: It's not the actual element that's being dragged - it's a browser screenshot that is, and that's up to the browser. There's no way to control that except to write your own backend or use a stored image of the thing being dragged - I can show you how to do the second thing.

Comment: I've used an image. If it's small, it at least avoids the opacity gradient.